# Using static friction and angle of force to determine the unknown mass of an object.

Tags: calculus, physics, classical-mechanics

I am pushing down on my lawnmower an angle θ=25 degrees below the horizontal with a force 750 N where the static friction coefficient between the  at surface and the trunk is μs=0.75. What is biggest lawnmower I will be able to move?

Here's my attempt:

The sum of all components in the y direction is N-mg-750sin(25)=0, which means N=mg+750sin(25).

The sum of all components in the x direction is 750cos25-fs=0, with fs being the static fiction. We know that fs=μs*N

Combining what we know is N and our previous equations together we have the sum of all x components being

750cos(25)-0.75(mg+750sin(25))=0
-->679.73-7.35*m-237.72=0
-->7.35m=442.01
-->m=60.14 kg

Am I understanding the use of static friction here correctly? I'd appreciate any input I can get.

Comment: as a user with 900+ rep and 7 silver badges, you are setting a terrible example for all new users when you don't **typeset your post!**

Answer (score 1):

Let be $F=750\,\mathrm N$, $\mu_s=0.75$, $g=9.8\,\mathrm{m\,s}^{-2}$ and $\theta=25^\circ$
$$\left\{\begin{align}
F\cos\theta-f_s&=0\\
F\sin\theta+mg-F_n& = 0\\
f_s&=\mu_sF_n
\end{align}\right.
$$
We have $f_s=\mu_s(F\sin\theta+mg)$ and $F\cos\theta=\mu_s(F\sin\theta+mg)$ that is
$$
m=\frac{F}{g}\left(\frac{1}{\mu_s}\cos\theta-\sin\theta\right)=60.14\,\mathrm{kg}
$$